# removing selected option from select list, on click - list disappears

Tags: jquery, html

It seemed relatively simple... I wanted a select list (#currentTags), in which - simply selecting an option would remove it from the list.

Here's my jquery:

```
        $('#currentTags').click(function(){
        var myList = $('#currentTags');
        myList.remove (myList.selectedIndex);
        })
```

When I run this, the whole select list disappears from my screen! If you have any idea what might be causing this, and a solution to making it work - I would be all eyes.

AMENDMENT: I had CSS on the list causing overflow to be hidden. Once I removed this, the list no longer disappeared. But the option in the select list doesn't get removed on click.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here  is you answer

You are doing
myList.remove(...) 
That will remove the #currentTags element.
So need to just remove selected option from currentTags

So use

```
$('#currentTags').find('option:selected');
```

Code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select').change(function(){
        $(this).find(":selected").remove()
    })
})
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/krunalp1993/CjGVs/

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: @wribit Always Welcome Please Accept as answer if helped you :)

Comment: @wribit Don't forget to click `✔` button. This is how StackOverflow works.

Comment: Done! Thanks, newbie here.. :)